# How do you change the length of an Angular Material Slider?

Tags: angular, slider

I am trying to put a slider into my application. However, the slider itself is too long and I am wondering if there is a way to easily change the length of it. Right now it is too long to fully fit into the container that it is in.

I have tried using CSS to change the width and the height, but this seems to not do anything.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, It would be nice if you could share the relevant code. It is hard to imagine what exactly you want to do without any peace of information.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this:

```
mat-slider {
  width: 400px;
}
```

You can check here in this link: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dyjdyxemkbl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-overview-example.css

You can try changing the value and checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

If its [Angular Material Slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview), you can apply the `width` css property to your `mat-slider` component, like in [the official example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dyjdyxemkbl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-overview-example.css).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that mat-slider has a class addressing the element via Material's stylesheet. As such generic addressing via a CSS class or ID goes nowhere.

**Example - not working:**

CSS:

```
.width-100pc {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <mat-slider
    class="width-100pc"
    min="0" max="100000" step="100">
    <input matSliderThumb>
  </mat-slider>
```

**Solution:**

As @Srikar Phani Kumar Marti pointed out, you need to address the element. This is done by updating your CSS class to:

```
.width-100pc, mat-slider.width-100pc {
  width: 100%;
}
```